# Error Whilng installing anything

Tags: apt, binary

hey guys im new to this whole linux thing.

when i do

```
sudo apt-get update
```

i get this

```
it:1 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease
Hit:2 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease                
Ign:3 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubunt bionic InRelease                 
Err:4 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubunt bionic Release                   
404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.54.217 443]
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease              
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/dawidd0811/neofetch/ubuntu bionic InRelease     
Hit:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Ign:8 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore                                    /   xUbuntu_18.04 ./ InRelease
Hit:9 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease             
Hit:10 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore  /x     .04 ./ Release
Hit:11 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease          
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fyrmir/livewallpaper-daily/ubuntu bionic       InRelease
 Reading package lists... Done                                           
 E: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubunt bionic  Release'     does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-4200/Packages' as    repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't    support architecture '4200'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-4200/Packages' as   repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease'   doesn't support architecture '4200'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-4200/Packages'  as repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease'   doesn't support architecture '4200'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-4200/Packages' as   repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease'   doesn't support architecture '4200'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-4200/Packages'   as repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease'   doesn't support architecture '4200'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-4200/Packages' as    repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/dawidd0811/neofetch/ubuntu bionic   InRelease' doesn't support architecture '4200'
 : Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-4200/Packages' as   repository 'http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't    support architecture '4200'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-4200/Packages' as repository 'http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't  support architecture '4200'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-4200/Packages' as repository 'http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't support architecture '4200'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-4200/Packages' as repository 'http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't support architecture '4200'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-4200/Packages' as repository 'http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease' doesn't support architecture '4200'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-4200/Packages' as repository 'http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease' doesn't support architecture '4200'
 N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-4200/Packages' as repository 'http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease' doesn't support architecture '4200'
: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-4200/Packages' as repository 'http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease' doesn't support architecture '4200'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-4200/Packages' as repository 'http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease' doesn't support architecture '4200'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-4200/Packages' as repository 'http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease' doesn't support architecture '4200'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-4200/Packages' as repository 'http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease' doesn't support architecture '4200'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-4200/Packages' as repository 'http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease'      doesn't support architecture '4200'
```

Comment: `4200` certainly isn't a valid architecture.